# Using jq to extract data from API that has no key

Tags: json, jq

I need to extract datas from an API which has no keys any idea how to do it?
How do I use jq to do this?

The Api output is like this:

```
[
  "1400",
  0,
  0,
  0,
  285697101361315840,
  562949953421312,
  "2021-09-08T01:28:00.000Z",
  false,
  0,
  0,
  0
]
[
  "1401",
  0,
  0,
  0,
  263179103224463360,
  0,
  "2021-09-08T01:28:00.000Z",
  false,
  0,
  0,
  0
]
...
```

So I need data from rows 2 to 11 for each top row, here 1400 and 1401, for example I can check whats on 5th row for 1400 and whats for 1401.

Comment: Please confirm that by `jq` you're referring to the Linux command-line executable `jq` (like `sed`, `awk`, etc) and _not_ jQuery.

Comment: Yes, sorry.
Updated tags.

Comment: "I need to extract values"; what values?

Comment: Data from rows 2 to 11 for each top row, here 1400 and 1401, for example I can check whats on 5th row for 1400 and whats for 1401

Comment: Please add the expected output to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [OP's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69100098/using-jq-to-extract-data-from-api-that-has-no-key#comment122135685_69100098):

> for example I can check whats on 5th row for 1400 and whats for 1401

---

If we loop over the arrays, we can use string interpolation to create the desired output using hard coded array indexes.

For example, index `0` and `5`:

```
jq --slurp --raw-output '.[] | "\(.[0]) - \(.[5])"'
```

Will show:

```
1400 - 562949953421312
1401 - 0
```

As you can test in this [online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/9n7L77qUep).